# ClassCastException with org.owasp.esapi.logger when deploying with JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss7.x, esapi

I'm trying to install JasperServer on a Jboss 7.1 server, and after a lot of trouble to successfully deploy the .war I downloaded on their site, when I try to log in I got this exception:

ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jasperserver].[default]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-7) "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a généré une exception  *(Translation : "servlet.service() for default servlet generated an exception")*: **java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger cannot be cast to org.owasp.esapi.Logger**

I made some research, and it seems that a solution would be to exclude the jboss.logmanager modul when deploying, using jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
I put the following xml file in my .WEB folder :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Do I have to declare this XML somewhere so it can be "read" by Jboss ? Do I have to put it somewhere else ? Does my xml file miss anything ?

Or, has anybody encountered issues like this when installing Jasper Server or something else, and has another solution ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: That's the wrong dependency to exclude. Plus you might need to exclude some others. One will be `org.jboss.logmanager.log4j`. What logging dependencies do you include in your deployment?

Comment: I found another dependency using log4j (apache.something) excluded that one, and in fact it works ^^ thanks anyway !